# PHP Code for Subscribe Block

Tags: php, web

```
<form action="mailer.php" method="post" novalidate>
<input  value="Your Name"  name="NAME"    class="autoclear name-newsletter"     >
<input  value="Your Email"  name="EMAIL"  class="email-newsletter"     >
<input  value="Your Phone"  name="PHONE"  class="phone-newsletter"   >
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="subscribe"  class="button-newsletter">
<label> * We will not forward your email address to any third party.</label>
</form>
```

I want to just set up a php to send an email with the information above, not a subscribe

Comment: Do you want to send the email to yourself or to the email from the form?  If you want to send the email to the address in the form, you will most certainly be attacked and your page will be turned into a relay for spammers.

Comment: So, what's the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mail function documented by php here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Execute the mail function on mailer.php using the post data.

EDIT

This code should work (Place it in mailer.

```
<?php
$message = 'Name:  '.$_POST['NAME']."\n".
           'Email: '.$_POST['EMAIL']."\n".
           'Phone: '.$_POST['PHONE'];

mail($to, $subject, $message)
?>
```

Comment: I can just want to send the name email and phone number to my email can you please provide of what the php script should be I am fairly new and am I a visually learned having a hard time

Answer (score 1):

The example below will send the email, but you should add captcha, and possibly other forms of security to prevent the form from being spammed.

Taken from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
<?php
$success = '';

$to      = 'you@example.com';
$subject = 'Newsletter Subscriber';
$message = 'Name:  '.$_POST['NAME']."\r\n".
           'Email: '.$_POST['EMAIL']."\r\n".
           'Phone: '.$_POST['PHONE'];
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  $success = "Success! Your email has been sent!";
}

?>
```

Comment: How do i make it show a success your email has been sent on the same page instead of redirecting?